# Firebase dynamic links reliability/ availability

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-hosting, firebase-dynamic-links

As I understand, firebase dynamic links is using firebase hosting and it is available on CDN edges around the world. Is there some documentation about reliability/ availability?
What can be done when it is down?

Answer (score 0):

There is [documentation article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/debug) that ought to help. Generally you can even generate the flowchart. There are some hints for some ios and android common issues.

If nothing will help, the doc advice to contact [Firebase Support Page](https://firebase.google.com/support).